# class prototypes not being read

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, methods

im learing c++.I was goofing around trying new stuff and wanted to use an object class `sub` in  class `object`.But i was getting error saying that the object of class `sub` not in not defined.I know how to solve this issue i just have to move class `sub` above class `object` so that the compiler knows that there is a class called `sub`.

But I feel like this will get annoying as my code grows bigger and bigger so i tried forward declaring class like we do for function prototyping.But this doesn't work as it gives me this error -

`'object::thing' uses undefined class 'sub'`

Here is the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class sub;
class object;

class object
{
private:
    sub thing;
    int ray;
public:
    void set(int n);
    void get() const;
};


class sub
{
public:
    int num;
public:
    void set_num(int n);
    void get_num() const;
};

int main()
{
    object ray;
    ray.set(4);
    ray.get();
}
```

Can you guys help me out??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a type is used in c++, at a minimum that type needs to have been declared previously.

However, in some cases, the type needs to be defined (complete) as well.

```
class A;

class B { 
  A a;    // error, because A needs to be defined   
};
```

In other cases, the type only needs to be declared (i.e. it can be incomplete):

```
class A;

class B { 
  A *a;    // fine, because A only needs to be declared   
};
```

If a type needs to be defined when it's used (as in your case), then you have no choice but to define it before hand. You could put the definition in a header file, but that file still needs to be included before the type is used.

Comment: thanks, can you explain why i dont need to define when i use pointer of object of class `A`?

Comment: @default-303 Pointers are a fixed size, so the compiler doesn't need the definition of `A` to make a pointer. In other words, it's allowed to be an incomplete type.

Comment: thanks a lot fellow programmer. Can you clarify one more doubt - If i move my class definitions in a different file and include the file as header then i dont need to care about how i organize my classes right ??

Comment: That depends. It's fine, so long as you don't have a circular dependency. In that case, you should be careful.